# Does dlopen(NULL, ...) stop libraries from being unloaded?

Tags: c, posix, dynamic-linking

## Background

I'm making an out-of-band API for working around a limitation of a layer between my plugin and my application.

The correct solution would be to update the middle layer to support the extra API, and that is in progress, but unfortunately that will take too long.

## Question

I am using `dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW)` in the application to search for symbols in the plugin. Will that prevent my plugin library from being unloaded until a matching `dlclose(NULL)`?

I'm assuming not, but I can always hope.

## Answer

Turns out that `dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW)` does not prevent my plugin from being unloaded. I'm going to look into something using `dladdr` to maybe work something out. I'll post it as an answer if I get time.

Comment: Since C standard does not have dynamic libraries (IIRC) which OS/Platform are you talking about (Mac OS X, Linux, Cygwin...).On Linux  possibly a better wayis to use `-z nodelete` linker flag or `RTLD_NODELETE` flag for `dlopen`.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka dlopen is POSIX, so I guess all of the above? Wouldn't dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NODELETE) prevent all libraries from unloading?

Comment: FWIW musl libc never unloads/closes dlopen'ed libs (dlclose is at least currently a no-op) until the application exits.

Comment: @tecywiz121 `dlopen` is but `RTLD_NODELETE` isn't (and `-z nodelete`). Method with `dlopen` and `dclose` should work but external user might still 'double-`dlclose`' the library on most systems.